Quarto publish resets CNAME
I want to use Github pages with a custom domain and have set everything up accordingly. I publish my website with the command quarto publish gh-pages. The problem is: Quarto deletes the CNAME file in the branch automatically when I use the publish command. The solution in this issue and this PR is to refer to it in _quarto.yml
project:
  resources: 
    - CNAME

did not work for me.
I also tried this, but it didn’t work:
project:
  resources:
    - "CNAME"

Terminal output:
user@user:~/Dokumente/Git-Repos/reponame$ quarto publish gh-pages
? Update site at https://username.github.io/reponame/? (Y/n) › Yes
Von github.com:username/reponame
 * branch            gh-pages   -> FETCH_HEAD
   46bab98..0380bd0  gh-pages   -> origin/gh-pages
Rendering for publish:

[ 1/19] blog.qmd
[../19] ....qmd
[19/19] index.qmd

Bereite Arbeitsverzeichnis vor (setze Branch 'gh-pages' um; war bei 46bab98)
Branch 'gh-pages' folgt nun Remote-Branch 'gh-pages' von 'origin'.
HEAD ist jetzt bei 0380bd0 Create CNAME
[gh-pages 1c02f36] Built site for gh-pages
 2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 2 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 CNAME
origin  git@github.com:username/reponame.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/reponame.git (push)
To github.com:username/reponame.git
   0380bd0..1c02f36  HEAD -> gh-pages

NOTE: GitHub Pages sites use caching so you might need to click the refresh
button within your web browser to see changes after deployment.

[✓] Deploying gh-pages branch to website (this may take a few minutes)
[✓] Published to https://username.github.io/reponame/

Solution:
It’s important to create the CNAME in your local repository and not (like me) with GitHub settings online. Then it worked for me.

Have you set a custom domain in Settings > Pages > Custom Domain on GitHub Pages? Perhaps try publishing once and getting the site working then adding the CNAME file and reference to it in _quarto.yaml as a separate commit.

Yes, I have tried this a lot of times. But the problem is that Quarto always deletes this CNAME again with the push.

My workaround is to set a new custom domain after every quarto publish command in github. That’s not very comfortable and I would be happy if there is any better solution.

I've found this works for me but I publish via a GitHub action rather than using quarto publish gh-pages locally each time, maybe trying that approach will help. I wrote up my solution to this the other day at https://blog.nshephard.dev/posts/quarto-cname/

@apfelpfluecker Maybe because the resources key should not be under project, but rather as a first-level key? (this is how it is defined on my website)

I got it now! The problem was that I created the CNAME in GitHub settings and not in my local repository.
I tried both options, resources as a project key and as a first-level key. For me, both worked. Thanks @ehudk.
@slackline Thanks for your option, I wanted to try it out this week but fortunately I have a solution now :)
